# Create line chart using value from SQL database

Tags: php, sql

So I've been following this tutorial: https://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/chart-line-database.php

I am trying to add a line chart to my website to display number of sales for each month.

This is an example on how my SQL table looks like:

```
| ID |  user   | sale_id |         date        |
|  1 | RVN4372 | 1341234 | 2020-09-22 17:31:32 |
|  2 | OVI6517 | 5452351 | 2020-09-22 15:14:43 |
|  3 | RVN4372 | 8452176 | 2020-09-17 16:23:54 |
|  4 | FOK8905 | 7421312 | 2020-09-17 11:23:11 |
|  5 | DIF9127 | 4236123 | 2020-09-15 15:32:26 |
```

This is how my current query looks like:

```
<?php
          
if($stmt = $link->query("SELECT user,COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE yearweek(DATE(date), 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1) GROUP BY user order by COUNT(*) DESC")){

$php_data_array = Array(); // create PHP array
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_row()) {
   $php_data_array[] = $row; // Adding to array
   }
}else{
echo $link->error;
}
//print_r( $php_data_array);
// You can display the json_encode output here. 
echo json_encode($php_data_array); 

// Transfor PHP array to JavaScript two dimensional array 
echo "<script>
        var my_2d = ".json_encode($php_data_array)."
</script>";
?>

<div id="curve_chart"></div>
```

This is how it looks like on my website:

[image: Image here]

So this basically groups the users, and count how many sales each user has. On the X axis is display the user's name, and Y axis total number of sales.

I want to change this, so in the X asix is display the month, and Y asis total number of sales. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: Hava been trying out some, but can't make it work. This is what I've got so far:

```
if($stmt = $link->query("
SELECT YEAR(date) 
as SalesYear,
MONTH(date) as SalesMonth,
COUNT(*) AS TotalSales
FROM sales
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
ORDER BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
AND COUNT(*) DESC
")){
```

Comment: Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one year then you need to group in Year-month combination.  Then change this query to this.

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(date),'-' MONTHNAME(date)) as ym,  COUNT(*)  FROM sales GROUP BY ym ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: That line didn't give me any value, but this one looks like it works: `SELECT MONTHNAME(date),COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY MONTH(date) order by MONTH(date) ASC`